# Combining samples at different resolutions

Tags: cluster-sample

I have a dataset of object sizes obtained from aerial photographs.
Different photographs, taken at different altitudes, give access to different information. When close to the ground, the area captured is smaller, hence a higher resolution and small objects can be identified. When further from the ground, the area is larger, and bigger objects can be detected (if an object is not entirely enclosed in an image, it is discarded).
There is no overlap between the pictures, taken serially for a given location.

Truncation problems set aside, what would be the best way to combine several images for estimation purposes? I am mainly interested in visualising an empirical distribution of these sizes, and eventually fitting a statistical model to it. Each different location is supposed to have a homogeneous distribution of sizes, and I want to group by location. I have access to the surface area captured by each photograph. At first, I thought of introducing some weights inversely proportional to it, but I'm second guessing it now.
For each location, I have up to four different photographs, with ratio of areas going up to about 100, and ratio of counts going up to about 10.